# Can Loquendo voices be used with festival or espeak?

Tags: linux, voice, tts

I'm trying different voices, including mbrola ones... but those are so far away from Loquendo's....

Also I've written a bash script to convert all documents to mp3, but anyway I get always the same set of voices, which are very ugly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think they are different at low level... so cannot be used so directly.

They use different techniques for synthesizing as far as I know.